# How do you change the Title Font for a WPF Chart in code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, toolkit

I have created a WPF chart programmatically and would like to change the Title's Font and color, I can set the chart's width and height but not the title, all the examples that I have found online show you how to do it through XAML. but I need to be able to do it all in code.

```
        this._chart.Width = this.ChartWidth;
        this._chart.Height = this.ChartHeight;
        this._chart.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        ....
        this._chart.Title ????
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the TextBlock control instead of the plain text:

```
this._chart.Title = new TextBlock 
{ 
    Text = "My title", 
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"), 
    Foreground = Brushes.Red 
};
```

The same approach can be used with the legend title. By the way you can use any WPF control, not only the text block.

```
this._chart.LegendTitle = new TextBlock { Text = "legend", Foreground = Brushes.Red };
```

If you want to change a style property like PloatAreaStyle, do it so:

```
var plotAreaStyle = new Style(typeof(Grid));
plotAreaStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Grid.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightBlue));

this._chart.PlotAreaStyle = plotAreaStyle;
```

Comment: @Vortex, just to follow up on this, I need to find the mechanism of setting values for the chart different properties, for example the Legend, or the chart plot area, In the asp.net charts things are quite easy to set however in WPF I just can't figure out how to set values without XAML. I would appreciate if you could demonstrate the mechanism on setting a chart property without XAML ie the legend or the chart plot area.

Comment: @ALIR.Bousari It would be better to specify exactly which properties you want to set or to demonstrate the xaml code which you want to rewrite. I assumed that the properties, examples of which you want to see, are LegendTitle and PlotAreaStyle.

Comment: @Vortex Tnx for the prompt response, I think I now understand the pattern. :-)